# How can I embed images in a video using C#.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, image, video, blender

Is there any API available by which I can embed my own images in a any Video file at certain points in the Video or between certain video frames ?

If not, I would like to study the formats of the files, e.g. study the format of an mp4 file and create the API myself. Please point me to any sites that reveals the MP4 files format that can be easily understood.

Please do not tell me the Applications already doing it. I want to do it myself through programming.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this site [Here](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html) It might help you and its free..

also check this [One](http://www.viscomsoft.com/products/videoeditgold/index.html), but it not free.